# jsp and struts framework

Tags: jsp, struts

I have a set of ten questions in a jsp. At present I'm showing ten of them at a time(writing a loop and iterating them in that loop in a single jsp)but my new requirement is I have to show only one question at a time and when user answers first question and clicks on NEXT button he should be able to see the second question and so on...here also I should use only single jsp... But how can iterate ten times the same jsp & and how can I store the values and at the end how can I submit all these values to a form? I'm using struts framework.

Comment: could you show us the code you've already built ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions

1. Use [Ajax](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/ajax.html) to submit the answer of each question as soon as it is answered and then load the next question (again using ajax).
2. Load all the questions in DIVs and show only one at a time. When user answers a question store the answer in some hidden field (`<intput type="hidden">`) and When he completes all the questions then submit all the 10 hidden fields with the form

Tell me if you need more clarification.